# How to know if there one or more Cyrillic symbol in String and count them (Kotlin)

Tags: string, kotlin, encoding, utf-8, cyrillic

I'm working on QR-parser. In my QR I have a field "encoding", which one shows us a string encoding ("1" = w1251, "2" = UTF8, "3" = KOI8-R). I need decode 1, 3 in UTF-8, so it's ok:

```
private fun checkEncoding(encoding: String, decodedString: String) =
    when (encoding) {
        "1" -> decodedString.toByteArray(Charset.forName("windows-1251")).toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        "3" -> decodedString.toByteArray(Charset.forName("KOI8-R")).toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        "2" -> decodedString
        else -> throw ErrorsBuilder.UNKNOWN_ENCODING_ERROR.unknownEncodingException(decodedString)
    }
```

But sometimes we get wrong QRs, which has encoding = 1, but string in UTF8.
We'd like to work with this situation, maybe anyone can help. We decided to make next logic: if string has Russian symbols -> do nothing with it, it's UTF8. else -> do `checkEncoding()`

First idea: check if they're Russian letters in string. I did this:

```
fun main() {
    val string1 = "Name=Филиал"
    val string2 = "Name=РЎС‡РµС"
    val string3 = "ФФФ"

    println(parse2(string1)) //false
    println(parse2(string2)) //false
    println(parse2(string3)) //true }

fun parse2(string: String): Boolean {
    return string.matches("[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+".toRegex())
}
```

How can u check that string has at least one Russian symbol with many English? Something like `matchesAny()`?

The second problem that in String "ST00011|Name=РЎС‡РµС" symbols "Р", "С" are Russian too. I decided to make some counter, which count Russian symbols from string and compare that number with string length.
But I don't know how to perform it.

So maybe u have any Ideas and better solutions for my situation? Or can give me the answer on question from Title?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'РЎС‡Рµ'.encode( 'cp1251').decode( 'utf8')` returns `Сче`, and vice versa: `'Счесть'.encode( 'utf8').decode( 'cp1251')` -> `РЎС‡РµСЃС‚СЊ`, or `'Филиал'.encode( 'utf8').decode( 'cp1251')` -> `Р¤РёР»РёР°Р»`. Hence, presence of Russian (Cyrillic) symbols by itself does not imply correctness… For instance - `'и'.encode( 'utf8').decode( 'cp1251')` -> `Рё` - both `и` and `Рё` are Russian: `Р` (U+0420,  *Cyrillic Capital Letter Er*) and `ё` (U+0451,  *Cyrillic Small Letter Io*)

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple regex check:

```
Regex("[\\u0400-\\u04FF]").containsMatchIn(inputString)
```